# Reflector for Java?

Tags: java, .net, decompiling

Is there a Java equivalent to [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)?

Edit: more specifically, decompiling is what I'm after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what little I know the functionality of .NET Reflector is available in pretty much all Java IDEs, including Eclipse. Just add a `jar` file to a projects and you can browse its classes just as you browse your own classes.

For the decompiler aspect (as opposed to the pure class browser) there are some alternatives as well. The JDK tool `javap` only decompiles to byte-code so it isn't really useful to get to the source code (but might help with getting an understanding of the code).

[JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) is a pretty popular decompiler in the Java world and it produces compilable Java code most of the time (some bytecode sequences aren't easily translatable to valid Java 'though, so some corner cases exist).

Comment: I'm looking for something to decompile class files if thats possible.

Comment: I believe JAD has not been updated in a long, long time ... better off using jd-gui for this

Comment: Also `javadecompiler-gui` is available via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/javadecompiler-gui). ;-)

Answer (score 15):

See [How do I decompile Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) There's a link there to [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/), which seems to be about what you're looking for.

**Edit:** Also see [Open Java *.Class Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314/open-java-class-files).

**Edit 2:** And [Best free Java .class viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202586/best-free-java-class-viewer), which specifically mentions .NET Reflector.

Answer (score 3):

You can get **JAD** for decompiling .class into .java. It's pretty good at it.

If you use **Eclipse** get the [jadclipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/) plugin too. You'll need to configure the path to the jad.exe. Next time you open a .class you'll see the decompiled source instead of the .class declaration. And you can browse with F3 too. It's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Java, but does [JBrowser](http://www.mmsindia.com/JBrowser.html) work for you?